# viewflipper only works android 9

Tags: java, android

I need to make an ebook in android studio that ne the bottom has a next button and a previous button to turn the pages.

I have the ebook in images (jpg), searching the web I have achieved a method to do it, with  but when creating everything and exporting the apk the application only works on a device with android 9 (Redmi note 7) and in Previous android versions stop after displaying the splash screen.

I have read that ViewFlipper consumes a lot and that causes the application to break, I have 2 questions

1) How can I do to repair the app and can it work with viewflipper?

2) If you cannot use viewflipper, which method do you recommend?

Note: the Ebokk has 111 images.

**MainActiviti.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class MainActivity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {


    android.widget.ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    Button next;
    Button previous;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewFlipper = (android.widget.ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        previous.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        if (v == next) {
            viewFlipper.showNext();
        }
        else if (v == previous) {
            viewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ViewFlipper
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/a1"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:background="@drawable/a2"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:background="@drawable/a3"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:background="@drawable/a4"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:background="@drawable/a5"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:background="@drawable/a6"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:background="@drawable/a7"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:background="@drawable/a8"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:background="@drawable/a9"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

 <!-- here I continue doing the same until I reach the last image -->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView111"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/a111"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </ViewFlipper>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Siguiente"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/next"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Atras"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide your logcat

Comment: @HB.I can't, I do tests on real devices because my computer is low resource and does not support the emulator

Comment: You can see your log in logcat in android studio with the device connected to your computer.. Read up on it, it's essential when developing applications.

Comment: 100 ImageView is too many for a single layout. Use ViewPager instead.